# Magento2: how to auto add grey bg color under photo

Tags: magento2, styles

Always to magento catalog I upload image .jpg with white bg color.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can now change all products background for transparent, and add a gray background for all products under the photo?

Like this:
[image: s]

update css theme.less:

```
.gallery-placeholder {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

img.img-responsive {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

img.img-responsive.product-image-photo.img-thumbnail.owl-lazy {background-color:#f2f2f2;}

img.img-responsive.product-image-photo.img-thumbnail {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.products-grid .product-item-info .product-top a.photo {background-color:#f2f2f2;}
```

update2: (The pictures stretched)
[image]

view.xml:

```
        <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
                 <transparency>false</transparency>
 <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
 <frame>false</frame>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
                 <transparency>false</transparency>
 <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
 <frame>false</frame>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your theme's **etc/view.xml** update / set "transparency" , "aspect_ratio" and "frame" to "false" like in both grid and list view , like example below :

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">        
     <transparency>false</transparency>
     <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
     <frame>false</frame>
</image>

<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">        
     <transparency>false</transparency>
     <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
     <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

after that flush cache and hope you will see the impact. Lastly using css you can set image box background to any color.

Comment: I update view.xml and cache flush. After this on web/css/theme.less I add below code: (update on question). Can you please check I correct do for our website? gerris.pl

Comment: But now I see images width and height are changed. (update2) on quesiton.

Comment: you need to adjust width and height or giv try by removing <aspect_ratio> tags first

Comment: Ok, now I detele tag <aspect_ration> and now width and height display correct. But now how to add grey bg color under image?

Comment: i belive the images you have uploaded are with transparent background so now using css you can add image box background to what ever color you want

Comment: Yes, but all images our products are .jpg    with bg white color. So in this case, impossible  auto add bg color via this solution?

Comment: if you have jpg with white background then none of the solution will work , unless you have transparent background. otherwise you need to add images with grey background instead of white. so its your choice which way is easier for you. ( in my opinion 2nd option will suit you / your client )

Comment: Ok. thank you for your time and help